# Dealing with a NullReferenceException after user is idle for over a certain amount of time

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the sub routine below that is used by my game managing web app to refresh the game list.

It works fine except when the user has been idle for more than 20 minutes.

After the user is idle for over 20 minutes, and the user tries to refresh the webpage or navigate within it, this error is always thrown:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
line 15 in refreshGameList()    // *** line 15 is the "Throw ex" line in the "Catch" statement below ***\

How can I prevent this?  Either by navigating the user back to the login screen or just "waking up" the app so it doesn't timeout like this?

Thanks

```
Public Sub refreshGameList(ByVal activePlanetID As Guid)
    Dim dbu As New gameUtils.DatabaseUtils
    With (Web.HttpContext.Current.Application)
        .Lock()
        Try
            Dim enviromentDataSet As DataSet = CType(Web.HttpContext.Current.Application("enviromentDataSet"), DataSet)
            If Not enviromentDataSet Is Nothing And enviromentDataSet.Tables.Contains("gameList") Then
                enviromentDataSet.Tables.Remove("gameList")
                Dim gameListParams As New ArrayList
                gameListParams.Add(New SqlParameter("@planetID", activePlanetID))
                dbu.fillDataSet(enviromentDataSet, "gamer_GetGameList", gameListParams, "gameList")
                .Item("enviromentDataSet") = enviromentDataSet
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally
            .UnLock()
        End Try
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the Catch. Just leave the Try and Finally. The Catch is dumping the stack trace and hiding the line that actually causes the error, without actually accomplishing anything productive. And who uses ArrayList any more?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thanks, will that fix anything or just point to the "real" error?  thanks again

Comment: Do you happen to have the session timeout set to 20 minutes?

Comment: @AndrewMorton In IIS, under the web apps application pool settings, the Idle time-out is set at 20 minutes.  I'm not sure if that's the same thing though

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell As you are using the Application cache, that will indeed be lost when the application pool is recycled. It is normally reasonable to set the recycling to happen once a day at some time the site is unlikely to be used (e.g. 3 a.m.). You will still need code like the_lotus showed, but there won't be as much overhead involved in re-creating the data.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks...where is that application cache recycle set?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Oh, hang on, I was thinking of the app pool recycling rather than the idle timeout. [Why is the IIS default app pool recycle set to 1740 minutes?](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/why-is-the-iis-default-app-pool-recycle-set-to-1740-minutes) is useful reading, but if using IIS 8.5 or later, rather than setting the time-out to 0 you could set it to, say, 40 minutes and set the "Idle time-out action" to "Suspend": [New feature in IIS 8.5: Idle worker-process page-out](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/erezs_iis_blog/2013/06/26/new-feature-in-iis-8-5-idle-worker-process-page-out/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, if the cache is empty, the second part of the If statement will still run. Change And with AndAlso

```
If Not enviromentDataSet Is Nothing AndAlso enviromentDataSet.Tables.Contains("gameList") Then
```

Caching in asp.net is a bit different than windows form. By default, a web server instance gets removed from memory if there's no activity for a specific amount of time. You need to have steps to rebuild the cache. You can to it in the global.asxa or when you fetch the data, something like.

```
Public ReadOnly Property EnviromentDataSet As DataSet
    Get
        If Web.HttpContext.Current.Application("enviromentDataSet") Is Nothing Then
            ' Load the information
        End IF

        Return CType(Web.HttpContext.Current.Application("enviromentDataSet"), DataSet)
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Would that rebuild be done in Application_Start?  thanks

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell I think so, but I suggest you look more into it to be sure